# Powershell Az Module Remove-AzAutomationAccount Does Not Remove RunAs Account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

When I remove an automation account in the Azure console it will remove the run as account connected to the automation account. When I run the 'Remove-AzAutomationAccount' command it will not remove the run as account. How can I remove the run as account through powershell when I'm removing the automation account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the run as account via `Remove-AzADApplication`, try the command as below, it works fine on my side.

```
$connection = Get-AzAutomationConnection -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -AutomationAccountName <AutomationAccountName> -Name AzureRunAsConnection
$appid = $connection.FieldDefinitionValues.ApplicationId
Remove-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $appid

Remove-AzAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <AutomationAccountName>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is what I was trying to figure out.